# Rails dynamic finders for many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, dynamic-finders

I have a model, "recipe". Here's the model;

https://github.com/mikeyhogarth/Nomelette/blob/master/app/models/recipe.rb

I am able to use dynamic finders to write code like this;

```
Recipe.find_all_by_name "spaghetti bolognaise"
```

but the following gives me a "NoMethodError"

```
Recipe.find_all_by_category 1
```

As you can see from the model I've had to revert to creating my own finder method for this functionality. Am I just missing something with the syntax or will dynamic finders only work on properties that are columns specific to a given model (not associations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recipe doesn't have a column/attribute named 'category' (because it's a many-to-many association), thus the method `find_all_by_category` isn't generated.

Here's what you can do

```
recipes = Category.find(1).recipes
```

It would have been different if a `Recipe belongs_to :category` and `Category has_many :recipes`. In this case:

```
recipes = Recipe.find_all_by_category_id(1)
```

Because the recipes table has a column named `category_id`...

Comment: Thanks man. In this case it needs to be many to many. No problem though, at least I know now!